# A short proof about irreducibility of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to show that the polynomial $y-x^3$ is irreducible in $F[x,y]$, where $F$ is an arbitrary field.
Here is my attempt.

Since $y-x^3$ is a linear polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $F[x]$, then if it were reducible, we would be able to express it as a product $y-x^3 = c f(y)$, where $c$ is a constant non-unit coefficient in $F[x]$ and $f$ a linear polynomial.

But then $c$ must also divide $x^3$, so that $c$ is either some power (up to degree 3) of $x$ or otherwise a unit in $F[x]$.
It cannot be the former, as $c$ must also divide $y$ and both $x, y$ are irreducible in $F[x,y]$.
It also cannot be the latter, as by choice $c$ must be a non-unit.
Thus $y-x^3$ is irreducible.

Assuming this is okay, I am also concerned about if I have correctly not used any underlying assumptions about the field $F$.
I am only really familiar with fields like $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and so on, and I am not sure if somewhere implicitly I have required the characteristic to be zero, or to be algebraically closed, or anything else.
Some confirmation here would be ideal too.

Comment: This looks correct. If you’re familiar with quotients, you can also check that the map $F[x,y]/(y-x^3) \rightarrow F[x]$ mapping $P$ to $P(x,x^3)$ is an isomorphism, which implies the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, which behind the scenes works a lot like your work, but by using irrationals can do much more "at once":

Pick a positive irrational number $\alpha$ and for $f(x,y)=\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}x^ny^m$, define
$$\deg_\alpha f=\max\{\,n+\alpha m\mid a_{n,m}\ne0\,\}. $$
Then, just as with "usual" degrees, we have $\deg_\alpha(fg)=\deg_\alpha f+\deg_\alpha g$.
The key point is but that for irrational $\alpha$, the map $(n,m)\mapsto n+\alpha m$ is injective.

Now assume
$$y-x^3=f(x,y)g(x,y).$$
So if $\deg_\alpha f=n+m\alpha$ and $\deg_\alpha g=r+s\alpha$ with $n,m,r,s\in\Bbb N_0$, then
$$ (n+r)+(m+s)\alpha=\deg_\alpha(y-x^3)=\max\{\alpha,3\}.$$
If we take $\alpha=\pi$ or $\alpha=\sqrt{10}$, say, wo obtain $\alpha$ on the right and conclude that $n+r=0$ and $m+s=1$, i.e., $n=r=0$ and one of $m,s$ is also $=0$, i.e., one of $f,g$ is constant.